# Display Css Styled Html Data on ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, html, css, kotlin

So, I want to display big html string that includes css (font-size, color, font-family, text-decoration etc..) part by part on a `ListView`. I know there are some options for this, like using `WebView` and `TextView` with `fromHtml()` method, but fromHtml isn't supporting css and WebView isn't divisible for ListView items. Any idea for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, You can create a listview in web view itself ! Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` very poor about css, but it isn't a tool showing a styled website content so it's enough for simple html texts.
When it comes to `WebView`, it's a good idea for showing complex html, css, javascript contents. You can use if you need. Certainly it isn't faster then `TextView`, but there are some performance improvements, as follows:

```
// In AndroidManifest

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    ...
>

<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
...

// In onCreate method from Activity class

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewId);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
this.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
this.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
else
    this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // older android version, disable hardware acceleration

// use this, for don't getting some errors.
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "HtmlString", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use CSS attributes on android's native `fromHtml()` but surely can use third party libraries as an alternative of `fromHtml()` which supports CSS. One of them can be [this one](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner).